# Replacing escape quotes with just quotes in a string

Tags: ruby, regex, string, escaping

So I'm having an issue replacing \" in a string.

My Objective:
Given a string, if there's an escaped quote in the string, replace it with just a quote

So for example:

```
"hello\"74"  would be "hello"74"
simp"\"sons would be simp"sons
jump98" would be jump98"
```

I'm currently trying this: but obviously that doesn't work and messes everything up, any assistance would be awesome

```
str.replace "\\"", "\""
```

Comment: Shouldn't `simp"\"sons` become `simp""sons` ?

Comment: @anubhava yes i'm sorry typo

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are being mistaken by how `\` works. You can never define a string as

```
a = "hello"74"
```

Also escape character is used only while defining the variable its not part of the value. Eg:

```
a = "hello\"74" 
# => "hello\"74"
puts a
# hello"74
```

However in-case my above assumption is incorrect following example should help you:

```
a = 'hello\"74'
# => "hello\\\"74"

puts a
# hello\"74

a.gsub!("\\","")
# => "hello\"74"

puts a
# hello"74
```

**EDIT**

The above `gsub` will replace all instances of `\` however OP needs only to replace `'"` with `"`. Following should do the trick:

```
a.gsub!("\\\"","\"")
# => "hello\"74"
puts a
# hello"74
```

Comment: I load the strings through a file, and if the string contains \" then I'm supposed to make it just "

Comment: @JakeSenior I have updated my answer. Please recheck, hope its helpful now.

Comment: The OP wants to replace `\"`, with `"`, your code removes all backslashes

Comment: @Stefan thanks for pointing out. I have edited it accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub`:

```
word = 'simp"\"sons';
print word.gsub(/\\"/, '"');
//=> simp""sons
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently trying `str.replace "\\"", "\""` but obviously that doesn't work and messes everything up, any assistance would be awesome

`str.replace "\\"", "\""` doesn't work for two reasons:

1. It's the wrong method. [`String#replace`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-replace) replaces the entire string, you are looking for [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub).
2. `"\\""` is incorrect: `"` starts the string, `\\` is a backslash (correctly escaped) and `"` ends the string. The last `"` starts a new string.

You have to either escape the double quote:

```
puts "\\\"" #=> \"
```

Or use single quotes:

```
puts '\\"' #=> \"
```

Example:

```
content = <<-EOF
"hello\"74"
simp"\"sons
jump98"
EOF

puts content.gsub('\\"', '"')
```

Output:

```
"hello"74"
simp""sons
jump98"
```